# Velocity 2.0: Unreadable Engine-Core-2.0 JAR

Tags: velocity

I downloaded Velocity 2.0 (Engine-Core-2.0 JAR) from the Apache Velocity website, http://velocity.apache.org/download.cgi#engine , and am unable to use it:

The JAR is unreadable in ZIP Viewers like PeaZip, is there something special about this JAR?

```
velocity-engine-core-2.0.jar Archive is not readable.
```

Also in Eclipse,

`Archive for required library: velocity-engine-core-2.0.jar' in project '..' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file`

Also, another question: Velocity used to be packaged as a single JAR, like velocity-1.6.jar or velocity-1.7.jar. Why is 2.0 different?

Comment: They are not readable because they don't exist, the response is 404. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download links don't take into account the selected mirror (the fix is underway). Meanwhile, replace "http://velocity.apache.org" in the jars URLs with the mirror URL.

EDIT: the fix went through, the links should now work.

Comment: Thanks working now. Could you also look at this new issue regarding "CommonsLogLogChute" Not Found - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118555/velocity-2-0-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-velocity-runtime-log-commonsloglo