# Velocity 2.0: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/CommonsLogLogChute

Tags: java, spring, velocity

On starting up my Web app with Velocity 2.0 I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
             org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/CommonsLogLogChute
    at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactory.createVelocityEngine(VelocityEngineFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(VelocityEngineFactoryBean.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 34 more
```

All dependencies have been satisfied. We are using

- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar
- commons-lang3-3.5.jar
- commons-io-2.5.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar (yes we do have Commons-Logging)

In applicationContext.xml the velocityEngine bean is defined as follows

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" 
class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean"/>
```

Any thoughts on this?

My file `velocity-engine-core-2.0.jar` only contains the following `.runtime` subpackages:

```
defaults, directive, parser, resource, visitor
```

but no `log` .

**UPDATE** The following overrideLogging = FALSE in the Spring Velocity Engine bean declaration solved the problem. **But why?**

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="overrideLogging" value="false" />
</bean>
```

I just followed a tip on 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory.html
but not sure what happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When overrideLogging is true, the class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute is still required by Spring while it has disappeared in Velocity 2.0, since Velocity now uses the slf4j logging framework.

You'll need to wait for an update of the Spring Velocity classes if you need overrideLogging to be true.

**Edit on June 21st, 2022** - Since version 2.3, Velocity does provide [Spring support](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/spring/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thank you but there won't be a new SpringVelocity -- it's deprecated now: Spring says: ""As of Spring Framework 4.3, Velocity support has been deprecated due to six years without active maintenance of the Apache Velocity project. We recommend Spring’s FreeMarker support instead, or Thymeleaf which comes with Spring support itself."

Comment: This comment was made before Velocity 2.0 went out. And as a result, someone will sooner or later contribute a Spring Velocity support package for 2.0 (I don't think that it would be too hard) which can be hosted on the Velocity site if Spring doesn't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity made a change in logging:

> Make Velocity use the base logger namespace 'org.apache.velocity'
>   unless specified with runtime.log.name in the configuration, and have
>   the runtime instance log with this base namespace, and other modules
>   log with children namespaces

CommonsLogLogChute added in before major version velocity 1.7:

> Add a CommonsLogLogChute that allows logging through commons-logging.

So you probably have an old jar or configuration in your runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

Alibaba implemented a support context package for that case: https://github.com/alibaba/spring-velocity-support

Just add to maven:

```
<!-- Spring Framework -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Context Velocity -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.alibaba.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.18.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But beware that your project now uses Velocity 2.0.